# Rails 4 - How to select a subset of columns, with column names, not including id? Select or Pluck?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Say I have a model, Bean, and I have the following query:

```
sqlParams = {}
sqlQuery = "overall_rating >= :rating"
sqlParams[:rating] = @rating

Bean.where(sqlQuery, sqlParams).select("name")
```

then I get:

```
#<Bean id: nil, name: "Kenya AA Wagamuga Auction Lot">
```

However, if I use:

```
Bean.where(sqlQuery, sqlParams).pluck("name")
```

then I get:

```
"Kenya AA Wagamuga Auction Lot"
```

What I want is this:

```
name: "Kenya AA Wagamuga Auction Lot"
```

I don't want that nil id, but I do want the column name. What's the best way to go about getting this sort of response? I'm passing it straight into a hash and then to a json for an http response. Keep in mind that I'm just ramping up on Rails, so let me know if I'm being silly. Thanks!

Comment: Select returns an id: nil. I don't want that element. Is there a good way to filter that out? I can't find a way to select all columns except certain ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't hurt to build the desired hash yourself.

```
Bean.where("overall_rating >= ?", rating).pluck('name').map do |elem|
  {'name' => elem}
end
```

Or, especially if you'll need more attributes, you can try this:

```
Bean.where("overall_rating >= ?", rating).map do |elem|
  elem.serializable_hash.slice('name', ...) 
end
```

Comment: your first example create one hash `{ 'name' => elem }`, all keys in hash should be uniq.

Comment: @Зелёный It returns an array of hashes so it's fine.

Comment: @JiříPospíšil thx for notice, i should sleep more than 3 hours.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Mapping the pluck was my last resort, but I'm grabbing 15-20 attributes, and I wanted to keep it as clean as possible. Let me check out the serializable_hash approach. Appreciate it =)

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using select, then filtering out the attributes I didn't want via map. I'm not sure the fastest solution, but this one seemed clean to me.

Thanks all for the input!

```
json_return[:reviews] = Bean.where(sqlQuery, sqlParams).limit(@count).reorder(@order_string).as_json.map do |bean|
  bean.except("id", "created_at", "updated_at")
end
```